# How to add more top bar in the Shell framework (Xamarin) after second level (before a item is selected)

Tags: shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use the Shell framework, delivery by Xamarin.Forms 4.0 and up. It Looks like a very good solution for most mobile application. (Here is the info[a link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/!)

I am using the VS 2019 Template (Xamarin.Forms ->Shell) to explain what I am trying to do. The template include two page (tab bar), Browse and About.... In the browse page, there is a list of element. Once you hit one element the systems goes directly to the detail page (navigation page shows a back bottom on the top, similar to master/detail page).

What Do I need?... After the user select one element of this list. I need to have a new page with top bar or additional menu. One page (default) is the detail page, and another page can be extra info about this item.

[See Pic Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdd2E.png)

Before I found 'Shell', I have a combination between TabbedBar/Navigation and MasterDetail. This is not recommended by the literature. There are many problem in the navigation from the master/detail view. So, I move on to a better solution. Looks like Shell in what is best for me.

The AppShell.xaml looks like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Main" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"  Route="Home" Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">

        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>

</FlyoutItem>
```

-----This create two tab bar and the bottom, which is perfect... However, after select on element of the list... I cannot find the way to add more tab (top) to the item selected.

I do not know hot to upload images.. but the VS 2019 template is the base to understand what do I need...

You help will be very appreciate.
Thanks in advance

EDIT: I added a picture...

Comment: Pictures would really help to understand. Whats a two page tab bar?

Comment: Hi, do you have a check with this sample code(https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals/). And some image will show more clearly about you want.

Comment: Thanls.. Saamer... I added a new pic. (Was really Easy... sorry I did not figure out before).  Junior Jiand: I saw this example, thanks, however, the hierarchical structure is in the compiling time. I need to create new tab after compiling, and depending the context (Item selected in the example). Thanks again for your help

Comment: @BlueOceans1st Okey ,got it.I have shared an answer. If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.Later replying in SO's Comment , remember to @ who you want to reply.Then he will get notification from your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If want to add Top Bar in `ItemDetailPage` .Just adding `ToolbarItems` property in **ItemDetailPage.xaml** as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App11.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Text}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, this is a good idea, but this is not a TopBar. I will add a variant of your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @BlueOceans1st Maybe mistaking your shared image want. Now I am not sure where need to add the bar.